# UseConcMarkSweepGC is deprecated, what is its replacement?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, deprecated, compiler-flags

A java program is giving this warning, with JRE 10.0.2:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
```

What is the recommended replacement for this switch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Dropping support for CMS and then removing the CMS code, or at least more thoroughly segregating it, will reduce the maintenance burden of the GC code base and accelerate new development. **The G1 garbage collector is intended, in the long term, to be a replacement for most uses of CMS.**

[From the Official JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/291)