# How to fix "Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'" error?

Tags: java

I have followed the instructions for getting started with codenameone in IntelliJ, yet when I set up my first project, based on the sample app I get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe" -Xms128m -Xmx1014m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=\"\" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=61544:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\reinp\OneDrive - beuthhs\beuth\Patterns und Frameworks\justtrivia\out\production\justtrivia;C:\Users\reinp\OneDrive - beuthhs\beuth\Patterns und Frameworks\justtrivia\src;C:\Users\reinp\OneDrive - beuthhs\beuth\Patterns und Frameworks\justtrivia\lib\CodenameOne.jar;C:\Users\reinp\OneDrive - beuthhs\beuth\Patterns und Frameworks\justtrivia\JavaSE.jar;native\internal_tmp;lib\impl\cls" com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator com.patrickreinbold.justtrivia.JustTrivia
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I saw that this has to do with Java 8 but in the IntelliJ instructions it says nothing about using Java 8. Is Java 8 always necessary or can codenameone run with Java 15, too?

EDIT:
I have now got it to open by simply copying the first line with the java command and removing the UseConcMarkSweepGC flag, then running it in terminal. But I am still not sure if that is "the correct way" to do it or if something could break along the way now.

Comment: This will help: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/363, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52239570/2987755, above JVM flag will work with java version<14 but not with greater than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the netbeans build script but this isn't really relevant as Codename One only supports Java 8 and Java 11 (at this time) so you should use one of those versions at the moment.

Answer (score 16):

Ignore unsupported VM options with another option:

```
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
```

Comment: If you can add this option, then you can also just remove the option that causes the error.

Answer (score 3):

run `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew users:

Comment out these lines

```
# /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options

## GC configuration
#-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
#-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
#-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

Then if you get

```
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m'
```

Update the logging file path

```
# JDK 9+ GC logging
9-:-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
```

to

```
# JDK 9+ GC logging
9-:-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
```

Sources

[Brew installed Elasticsearch 7.9.2 failing on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64190908/brew-installed-elasticsearch-7-9-2-failing-on-macos)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57993824/2237510

Answer (score 0):

i had the same i change the version from 21 to 11 (you can check with your version first),
be sure that the version is updated from cmd with this command

```
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
```

after that i go to wrapper.config and i chnage

```
#wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java
```

with my path to java

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java
```

i execute StartSonar.bat and now is OK